# Check Condition in column _Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, time

Data frame: Existing

```
+------+----------+
| SHOP |   TIME   |
+------+----------+
| AAA  | 08:52:00 |
| BBB  | 08:52:00 |
| BBB  | 08:57:00 |
| CCC  | 09:00:00 |
| CCC  | 09:00:00 |
+------+----------+
```

Data frame: Required

```
+------+----------+------------+
| SHOP |   TIME   |  CATEGORY  |
+------+----------+------------+
| AAA  | 08:53:00 | Work Time  |
| BBB  | 08:57:00 | Break Time |
| CCC  | 09:00:00 | Break Time |
| CCC  | 09:00:00 | Break Time |
+------+----------+------------+
```

BREAK TIME - HH:MM:SS
a)Shop – AAA
    Between 08:54:00 to 09:00:00
    Between 11:45:00 to 12:45:00
    Between 01:30:00 to 01:37:00

b)Shop – BBB
   Between 08:54:00 to 09:00:00
   Between 12:00:00 to 12:30:00
   Between 01:35:00 to 01:42:00

Im new to python. Tried diff combinations but finding it difficult. Is there an simple way?. 
Sample method

```
def categorize(row):
  if row["SHOP"] == "AAA" and row["TIME"] == "11:45:00":
    return "Break Time"
  else:
    return "Work Time"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to categorize this which can be a little too daunting is the following in which through multiple np.where conditions you define which cases should be written as 'Break Time' and in the end if not will be 'Work Time'

```
df['Category'] = np.where((df['SHOP']=='AAA') & (df['TIME'] >= '08:54:00') & (df['TIME'] <= '09:00:00'), 'Break Time', 
                 np.where((df['SHOP']=='AAA') & (df['TIME'] >= '11:45:00') & (df['TIME'] <= '12:45:00'), 'Break Time',
.......
,'Work Time')) ### as many closing brackets as opening np.where conditions
```

Comment: works. thanks . I converted time to Datetime and applied this code.